# Absolute Centered DIV Quirks between IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a fiddle with some CSS and HTML that successfully centers a div on the page and contains no fixed widths, just percentages.

http://jsfiddle.net/h9ZY4/

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Centered Div</title>

<style type="text/css">

body{
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.QuoteContainer{
    /* Contains Quote Name, Quote Text */   
    height: 50%;
    width: 80%;     
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: table;
}
.QuoteWrap{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.QuoteTop{
    /* Quote Text */
    background-color: #515151;
    background-image: url('Quotation.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 20px; 
    font-size: 18pt;  
}
.QuoteBottom{
    /* Quote Name */
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="QuoteContainer">
    <div class="QuoteWrap">
        <div class="QuoteTop">Vivamus feugiat hendrerit tortor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus eu rhoncus nisi. Nunc metus mi, condimentum eget mauris nec, ornare ullamcorper nunc. Curabitur luctus augue id enim consequat ornare. Sed enim justo, fringilla ac ultricies a, sodales eu massa?</div>
        <div class="QuoteBottom">Michael Smith</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that it renders correctly in Chrome, but not in IE.

Anyone have any ideas how I can get IE to display the same?

Comment: -*sigh*- I thought IE11 was better. `display:table` seems to be the issue.

Comment: Ensure that your page has a valid DOCTYPE declaration. This is required but also prevents some quirky behaviour in IE.

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of believing Chrome is correct and IE is always wrong. Use a validator to see if any of your html or css is incorrectly written instead of assuming Chrome is right/IE is wrong.

Comment: @AndyG jsfiddle automatically adds `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the demo frame. In this case, that can't be what causes the problems.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Fh9ZY4%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 according to that, the only error is a second `<body>` tag, which is caused by jsfiddle's automatic adding of a `<body>` tag around the entered code. That doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: @Joeytje50 I know that jsfiddle adds the DOCTYPE, I'm referring to the actual page. The code posted here hints that the DOCTYPE is missing.

Comment: I understand...but still, default-blaming IE (though many times for good reason) as "wrong" and default-praising Chrome as "right" are reflexes that should be contemplated. Note OP says "renders correctly" in Chrome, as if Chrome is automatically "right"....just saying OP's code "renders the code the way he/she wants" is more accurate.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Good point. IE is often the scapegoat and usually takes the blame. For what it's worth, Chrome has many bugs too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display is useless as soon as you use float or absolute position.

Obviously, the XY auto margin technique via coordonates is not working in IE11 but `display;table` does. So instead making a mix of methods , use one that works :).
**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mCJua)**

```
body{
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
}
html, body ,
.QuoteContainer{
  height:100%;/* inherits window's/parent's height */
  width:100%;/* inherits window's/parent's width */
  margin:0;
}
.QuoteContainer {   
    display: table;
}
.QuoteWrap {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.QuoteTop{
  /* Quote text */
  background-color: #515151;
  background-image: url('Quotation.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px; 
  font-size: 18pt;  
  width: 80%;  
  margin:auto;
}
.QuoteBottom{
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 80%;  
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: I usually run away from absolute positionning, i just found here one extra reason :) ...